Characterize vector space of matrices satisfying $\sum_i m_{ij} = \sum_j m_{ij} = 0$
Consider the vector space of real $n\times m$ matrices, satisfying:
$$\sum_i a_{ij} = \sum_j a_{ij} = 0$$
(The first one for all $j$, the second one for all $i$)
I have two questions:

What is a "nice" basis for such matrices? By nice, I mean one that makes immediately obvious what are the kind of matrices satisfying these equalities. Equivalently, "nice" = "sparse". If a basis is too complicated, I'd be satisfied by a set of sparse vectors that span this space.
I am interested in the orthogonal space, of matrices $b_{ij}$ such that $\sum_{ij}a_{ij}b_{ij}=0$ whenever $a$ is of the above form. What is the form of the matrices $b_{ij}$ ?

I have two conjectures

That the matrices with two $+1$ entries at positions $(i,j)$ and $(i',j')$ and entries $-1$ at $(i,j')$ and $(i',j)$, for some $i\ne i'$ and $j\ne j'$, span this space. But I think this is more than a basis (i.e., all such matrices are not independent).
That $b_{ij}$ must be of the form $b_{ij} = f_i + g_j + c$, where $c$ is a constant. I have not been able to prove this.



Consider the basis $E_{i,j}$ for $M_n(K)$ with zero entries everywhere except for the position $(i,j)$. Now pick the ones you need.


@DietrichBurde Not sure I understand your notation. What is $M_n(K)$?

Please edit, I added a conjecture for 2.

$M_n(K)$ is the space of all $n\times n$-matrices. Here it is $M_{n,m}(K)$. The $E_{ij}$ are the standard basis elements. You'll see what you need when you do a small example, like $m=n=3$.

Sorry, but what is $K$ ?

$K$ is any field (which always contains $0$ or $1$ for our entries). You have $K=\Bbb R$, but it works in general for this basis.

Also please see the two conjectures I just added.

Please edit your post to show your experiments for small values of $(m,n)$, to clarify what you mean by "nice" in your question 1. And better focus on one question, with some attempts.

@AnneBauval By nice I mean sparse.

@AnneBauval Yes, I just added this edit. So it's not a basis. But does it at least span the space?

I have edited the question, since I realize that for my purposes, I don't really need a basis. Just a set of vectors that span this space and that is sufficiently sparse that it "illuminates" the structure of the space.

Yes it spans the space. One way to approach it is to take such a matrix, add some of these elements to make the first row 0, etc. $\quad$   Think about why the dimension is $ (m-1)(n-1)$, and how we can use that to select elements that form a basis.

I know why the dimension is $(m-1)(n-1)$ (that's $nm$ minus the number of constraining equations ... and I guess one equation is redundant?). But I'm not sure how to select a subset of these vectors to make a basis. @CalvinLin

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293024/properties-of-zero-line-sum-matrices, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/the-orthogonal-complement-of-the-space-of-row-null-and-column-null-matrices, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623551/dimension-of-vector-space-of-matrices-with-zero-row-and-column-sum


Your space is defined by $(m-1)+(n-1)+1=m+n-1$ (clearly independent) equations:
$$\forall j<m\quad a_{n,j}=-\sum_{i<n}a_{i,j}$$
$$\forall i<n\quad a_{i,m}=-\sum_{j<m}a_{i,j}$$
$$a_{n,m}=\sum_{i<n,j<m}a_{i,j}.$$
Its dimension is therefore $mn-(m+n-1)=(m-1)(n-1)$, with basis
$$E_{i,j}-E_{n,j}-E_{i,m}+E_{n,m}\quad(i<n,j<m).$$

Its orthogonal is defined by the $(m-1)(n-1)$ independent equations:
$$b_{i,j}=b_{n,j}+b_{i,m}-b_{n,m}\quad(i<n,j<m).$$
A basis (of $m+n-1$ vectors) is therefore:
$$E_{n,j}+\sum_{i<n}E_{i,j}\quad(j<m)$$
$$E_{i,m}+\sum_{j<m}E_{i,j}\quad(i<n)$$
$$E_{n,m}-\sum_{i<n,j<m}E_{i,j}.$$



Thanks! I was getting close, but now it's crystal clear.

@a06e Is it clear to you that these form a basis, esp that they are linearly independent? If so, can you explain why in your own words? (Note that just having the dimension match isn't sufficient, but it could be with other conditions in place.)

@CalvinLin Not really. I did not think through the basis part (as I said, spanning is enough for my purposes). Is there an intuitive "graphical" reason for why they are independent? I'd bet something "diagrammatic" could work ...

The fact that they span that space comes directly from the way they are deduced from the relations. They are therefore independent because their number is equal to the dimension of that space (= ambient dimension minus number of independent equations).

If I understand correctly you basis for the $b$-matrices gives exactly the same as what I had in my OP, right? Just confirming.

Not the basis but the equations, yes.
